Product of iid random variables contradiction
I was working through some econometrics problems, and my professor used the result that the product of iid random variables is iid, but I've seen some posts that this might not always be the case.
My professor: consider the linear model: $y = \textbf{x}'\boldsymbol{\beta} + e, y \in \mathbb{R}, \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \textbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\{y_i, \textbf{x}_i, \textbf{z}_i\}$ are iid. Thus, the products $\textbf{z}_i \textbf{x}_i, \textbf{z}_i y_i$  are iid. Is this because we are in a sense 'drawing them together'? (I.e. iid around the brackets).
What's the difference here? What context is each result applicable or misleading?

$\textbf{z}_i \textbf{x}_i$ would probably not be independent of $\textbf{z}_i y_i$ but would be independent of $\textbf{z}_j \textbf{x}_j$ if $i \not = j$

Yes, the claim is they are each (separately) iid. Is there a way to justify this?

"the products $\mathbf z_i\mathbf x_i, \mathbf z_iy_i$" won't be iid except under extremely special circumstances because common to each pair is a factor $\mathbf z_i.$  The duplicate provides a general and immediately applicable result, regardless of how this question is intended to be interpreted.

I don't see how that answers the question. It's a very measure theoretic based answer to the independence question, but I don't see how we get to identically distributed.

That's irrelevant because the products already fail to be independent!

Maybe I didn't phrase the question in a good way. I'm not interested in $z_i x_i, z_i y_i$ together per se (I'm not asking about the common factor). Just focus on the case of $z_i x_i$. Is the variable $z_i x_i$ iid?

The variable $z_ix_i$ is the result of the function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x_1,x_2)=x_2x_1$ (multiplication).  The duplicate explains that independence of $(x_i,z_i)$ and $(x_j,z_j)$ implies independence of $f(x_i,z_i)$ and $f(x_j,z_j).$

Okay, so then they are independent, but then how do we get to identically distributed? I.e, is $f(x_i, z_i)$ iid?

That's a triviality: when $X$ and $Y$ are (possibly vector valued) random variables with the same distribution, then $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ must have the same distribution, too.
